# NodeJS Application stops instantly after start

Tags: node.js, web-applications, localhost, httpserver

I am trying to run a NodeJS application on Windows 7. It was created on a MacOSX and it worked fine, started it on a CentOS too and it's OK, but when I run it on Windows with

```
     npm start
```

Node spits out the usual starting of a line:

```
     C:\Git\My.App.2014>npm start

    > MyApp@0.0.1 start C:\Git
    > node ./bin/www

    C:\Git\My.App.2014>
```

And instead of running the server, it just stops instantly. Any ideas?

Comment: Your start command is `node ./bin/www`?  Is your script called `index.js`?  If you run `node bin\www\index.js`, what happens?

Comment: It starts :-). Slowly but yes, thanks a million! Didn't realize that it's a different executable file. I run "node bin\www\" and after a couple of seconds it starts the server